# Combining browse method with os.listdir file sorting script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, directory, operating-system

I'm a novice python programmer and i found two pieces of code that combined would basically do what i want from the program i am building. But i have a problem to get them working together. browse_button is a directory browse method that gives me the directory that i would want to do my other method search the sort_button. It would sort files into and if they do not exist it makes the folders. Then it puts the files with specified extensions into those folders.

I have tried to make this work for a few days and i feels stuck. I dont get the second part of the program working with the browse part. Now i get this error when i press the sort button:
"
names = os.listdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' 
"

But i feel dont know why it doesnt have the directory since i can view the directory on the screen before i press the sort button. Can someone explain the problem for me please? <3

```
""" Filesortingprogramm """ 
import os    
import shutil    
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called folder_path
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

root = Tk()

folder_path = StringVar()

label0 = Label(root, text="Filesorter")
label0.config(font=("Courier", 25))
label0.grid(row=0 ,column=2)
label1 = Label(root, text="open folder to be sorted")
label1.config(font=("Courier", 10))
label1.grid(row=1, column=2)
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=folder_path)
lbl1.grid(row=2, column=1)

button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button2.grid(row=3, column=3)

def sort_button()
    path = folder_path
    path = str()
    folder_name = ['text','kalkyl']
    names = os.listdir(path)
    for x in range(0,2):
        if not os.path.exists(path+folder_name[x]):
            os.makedirs(path+folder_name[x])
    for files in names:
        if ".odt" in files and not os.path.exists(path + 'text/' + files):
            shutil.move(path+files, path+'text/'+files)
        if ".ods" in files and not os.path.exists(path + 'kalkyl/' + files):
            shutil.move(path+files, path+'kalkyl/'+files)
button3 = Button(text="Sort", command=sort_button)
button3.grid(row=4, column=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: solved it with adding nilename to global and using os.chdir(filename) in the sort_button instead